# Arduino Bluetooth Serial

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, baud-rate

I keep getting weird problems working with the Arduino bluetooth, and before I go buy another I wanted to see if anyone had some insight.

Despite setting the Serial monitor and Arduino baud rates both to 9600, I get a mismatch and all the outputted characters are garbled. Additionally, when I try and connect from a Windows computer, using Serial.println("Words") gets caught in Serial.read(), and Serial.read() ends up returning "w" from "Words" (I know because changing the first letter results in a different value from Serial.read(). I'm very confused, and any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try using readString() instead and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

How did you connect the Bluetooth module ?
Sometimes the USB and Bluetooth module fight for control of the rx/tx.
If you use an Arduino mega, you could use the Serial1's tx/rx pins, or simply use SoftwareSerial library.